# Create RPM bundle

Tags: linux, rpm

I have list of following RPMs:

rpm1 rpm2 rpm3 rpm4

They are not dependent between each other.

I want to create master rpm which when I install will install all of those (1 to 4). I dont think that a good solution is to create rpm which will have dependency to all of those and will do nothing.
I want to create some kind of bundle, so when I install that "master rpm" all of those will be installed.
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A meta-rpm that depends on the other rpms is, quite likely, the correct answer.

rpm packages really can't contain other packages and automatically install them. You can't interact with the rpm database *while* an rpm is being installed. It is locked.

The other thing you could do would be to have a yum repository and create a group which listed all the rpms and then use yum to install the entire group.